# Pronouncing さ and ざ

Tags: pronunciation

How do you pronounce さ and ざ in Japanese? I understand that they are voiced and voiceless but how do you say them? I am currently learning Japanese.

I am English, I can say "bus" and "buzz". However, it's very hard to say the differences between Sa and Za in Japanese.

How do I produce the sounds before I articulate them all?

Comment: This question is a duplicate of your previous question and will be closed as such. If you have a different question, try to explain why this question is distinct from the previous one, or alternatively you can edit your previous question to reflect your question more accurately.

Comment: Also note that SE functions differently from the typical forum. It uses a Q&A format that is not suitable for discussions. While it is normal to recreate a post in a typical forum, here at SE we prefer to have posts neatly redirected to other posts which have the same issue, or where the same issue has been resolved in another post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this?
In English, you can say, "he **sa**w a ghost" ("saw" sounds roughly like さ, at least if we're just starting to get a feel for it), and you can say, "he's a ghost" ("he'**s a**" is close to being like ざ).

Comment: Thank you so much, Ned Ralf! How would you say something like Ohayo Gozaimasu or Zassan for example?

Comment: If you go to Jim Breen's website and type in おはようございます, there is a black arrow to the left of the entry that lets you listen to the pronunciation. Try here http://www.edrdg.org/cgi-bin/wwwjdic/wwwjdic?1C

Comment: Maybe it's just me, but this answer leaves a lot to be desired. The 'sa' in 'saw' sounds closer to そ than さ for me. The "he's a" example is entirely dependent on how fast/clearly a person is pronouncing it.

Comment: Dear Yushi, if the speaker is following standard American or British phonological rules, the letter <s> in English is pronounced either as a /s/ or a /z/, depending on the voicing of the following sound. Consequently, since the indefinite article <a> is voiced in the phrase <he's a ghost>, the preceding letter <s> should be pronounced as the phone [z]. This phenomenon is called regressive assimilation. Whether a person actually pronounces the <s> as a [z] depends, of course, on how much importance that person attaches to standard pronunciation.